# how to get facebook api access token without asking user to login?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I've been reading similar questions, but none of them works for my case.

I'm building a webpage about a city, say new york. What I would like to do is to have a box containing embedded facebook posts about new york city on the page. So I figure that I would need to use the facebook /search api and search "type = post". Since v2.0, facebook api no longer support search for public posts, so I would have to use v1.0.

Here comes the problem:
It is impossible to use the **app access token**, which is App ID|App secret, because I created my app after v2.0 was introduced, so my app can only make api calls supported by v2.0. But if I use **user access token**, it doesn't make any sense for my case, because people are supposed to come to my page to view the city information, there is no point to ask them to login their facebook account.

So how can I get the token I need to do the api call? It seems to be very simple, but I'm very confused right now. I just need to search for public data, no need to touch user information.

Or can I just login to my account and get the access token every time people visit this page? Stupid...

Comment: It's not impossible, and indeed it is the way, to use an app access token.

Comment: do you mean i should use the app access token? but like i said my app can only call those api supported by v2.0. if i use app access token, it will just give me an error like "search for public posts has been deprecated"

Comment: If that's true about /search, then using a user token wouldn't change things, right?  I guess it's unclear what kind of data you're trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

The public post search is no longer available in Graph API v2.0, independent from the type of the Access Token. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> Public Post search is no longer available. (`/search?type=post&q=foobar`)

Comment: Does this mean that as long as I create my app after API v2.0 was lauched, I can't use this app to make "search public posts" api call no matter what kind of token I use?

Comment: Yes! You can't... And for v1.0 apps this will stop to work on may 1st 2015

Comment: I write a piece of code, initialize js SDK with my app id, use the temporary token they give you when you play around with facebook api explorer, and make the search for public posts call. It works perfect. I`m all set if the token is not temporary... You`re wrong, It depends on the type of token

Comment: It dosn't work in the Graph API Explorer using v2.0: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=search%3Fq%3Dnike%26type%3Dpost&version=v2.0 The result is `{"error": {"message": "(#11) Post search has been deprecated", "type": "OAuthException", "code": 11}}` And even (like I wrote) you use the Post Search with v1.0, it will stop woking May 1st 2015.